# cocos2d python can't show UI in mac

Tags: python, macos, cocos2d-iphone

When I run `cocos2d(python)` hello example in mac pro from terminal, I use sudo, but no UI show, no warning no error, what I missed?

It worked well when I first ran my MacPro x64, but later when I reinstalled some packages, it did not.
Maybe the pyglet's 1.1.4 version can't support x64, but I am not very sure.

```
#
# cocos2d
# http://cocos2d.org
#
# This code is so you can run the samples without installing the package
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
#

import cocos

class HelloWorld(cocos.layer.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super( HelloWorld, self ).__init__()

        # a cocos.text.Label is a wrapper of pyglet.text.Label
        # with the benefit of being a cocosnode
        label = cocos.text.Label('Hello, World!',
            font_name='Times New Roman',
            font_size=32,
            anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

        label.position = 320,240
        self.add( label )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # director init takes the same arguments as pyglet.window
    cocos.director.director.init()

    # We create a new layer, an instance of HelloWorld
    hello_layer = HelloWorld ()

    # A scene that contains the layer hello_layer
    main_scene = cocos.scene.Scene (hello_layer)

    # And now, start the application, starting with main_scene
    cocos.director.director.run (main_scene)

    # or you could have written, without so many comments:
    #      director.run( cocos.scene.Scene( HelloWorld() ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX Mavericks it works using sudo. Without sudo I had the same problem.

sudo python samples/hello_world.py

Comment: I add sudo, but it can't show. About a month ago, it work ,but not now.I don't know what happened with osx

Comment: I rechecked again, but unfortunately it seem it only worked 'accidentially' when I called it with sudo, because after the first two calls it stopped working again :(